# How to check runtime type conformance of boxed primitives?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I'm clashing regularly with a problem of checking runtime type conformance in generic classes parametrized with primitives. Assume

```
private def runtimeTypeOf(o :Any) =
    runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).classSymbol(o.getClass).toType

class TupleType[T1 :TypeTag, T2 :TypeTag] {
    def unapply(o :Any) = o match {
        case (v1, v2) if runtimeTypeOf(v1) <:< typeOf[T1] && runtimeTypeOf(v2) <:< typeOf[T2] => Some()
        case _ => None
    }
}

val LongString = new TupleType[Long, String]
(1L, "2") match { case LongString() => true; case _ => false }
```

Above match will return false, as `v1` is `java.lang.Long`, while `typeOf[T1]` is justa scala `Long`.

Anyway to get a boxed, runtime type out of `typeOf[T1]` ?